# Assassins Creed 3 invisible coach bug

Tags: pc, assassins-creed-3

I have a very annoying bug where coach is always invisible, in cut-scenes and in general. The level of stupidity is really annoying as people literally sit in the air and horses pull them. Not only that, I can't seem to leap in in some missions where hiding is required. Anyway to fix this?[image]

Answer (score -1):

You will have to wait for ubisoft to release a patch, sadly you cannot "fix" this yourself.

Comment: I've been playing AC3 on the PC the last week or so and I've not had this bug. Is it isolated to certain PC setups? Do you have a source to confirm that this needs to be patched by Ubisoft?

Comment: I applied 6 patches or so in a row. I suspect this may has to do something with v-sync off(as many game adjust their time clock to frames as well causes some physics problems like in Skyrim). I have no time to test it right now.